# Whats the difference between *(a+b) and (*a+b)

Tags: c, ansi-c

A friend helped me with this code and I don't understand how it works. in the 5th line is (*pp-97)*4 basically the size of the char 110 so (110-97)*4 or the scanned value of pp? Thanks

```
char *pp =(char*)malloc(110);
printf("Enter text: ");
scanf("%s", pp); 
*pp = *(pp + n); 
int f = (*pp - 97)*4;
```

Comment: Does this look like Java to you?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: I'm totally confused. What do you want by this code? 97 is the ascii of 'a'

Comment: @ luchian I thought someone would know as its not that different from java

Comment: @ halelfits a small chunk of a larger program I just tried to understand this part

Comment: @jeniffer_214 I keep seeing you asking these questions in the comments. Do you have any idea what that f is used for? You seem to be asking us to make sense of it. But how can we make sense of it when we don't have the context of this code? We told you what this snipet does technically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `*pp` is equivalent to `pp[0]`, and generally `*(pp + n)` is equivalent to `pp[n]`, so

```
*pp = *(pp + n);
```

could also be written `pp[0] = pp[n];`, that copies the `char` at offset `n` to the first `char` at offset 0.

```
int f = (*pp - 97)*4;
```

and this could be written

```
int f = (pp[0] - 97)*4;
```

so 97 (the ASCII value of `'a'`) is subtracted from the first `char` in the block `pp` points to, and that difference is multiplied with 4.

Comment: so is the 97 subtracting from the ASCII value as well i.e. a-b (97-98)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, the idea is to get the offset of that `char` from `'a'` to get the appropriate index into the Morse-code array.

Comment: int f = (pp[0] -97)*4; lets say pp is 'abc' (97-97)*4

Comment: No, `pp` is a pointer to `char`, so it's not `'abc'`. It could point to `"abc"`, though. Then for `n == 0`, it would produce `int f = (97 - 7)*4;`. Each Morse code is aligned at a multiple of 4 from the start of the array, the first being the Morse code for 'a'. So if the `char` is e.g. `'d'`, the difference is `'d' - 'a' = 3`, and the offset into the Morse-code array is `4*3 = 12` because there are 3 Morse-codes (for 'a', 'b' and 'c') of four symbols (filled up with spaces if the actual code is shorter) before the code for `'d'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weird snippet.

This line basically declares a string of size 110:

```
char *pp =(char*)malloc(110);
```

These two lines grab input from users:

```
printf("Enter text: ");
scanf("%s", pp);
```

Now this is where things start to get weird.

```
*pp = *(pp + n);
```

The line above changes the first character of this string to the nth char in the string.

```
int f = (*pp - 97)*4;
```

Now in terms of this line. Here you are derefrencing the pointer pp. When you derefrence this pointer it will be first char that pp is pointing too. The value of this char will be converted to an integer (its ASCII representation) and then subtract 97 (which is the ASCII value of `a`) and then multiplied by 4.

Comment: "The line above moves the pointer by n" no it doesn't. It assigns the char at `pp+n` to the first char that `pp` points to. The pointer is not moved.

Comment: Wrong, the `*pp = *(pp + n);` expression doesn't change the pointer. It only copies the character at index `n` to index 0, i.e. it overwrites the first character with the last of the string.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You're right. I saw plus beside a pointer and did not stop to think. Please see my edits

Comment: @tristopia You're right. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *pp = malloc(110);
printf("Enter text: ");
scanf("%s", pp); 
pp[0] = pp[n]; 
int f = (pp[0] - 'a')*4;
```

In C, array operator is the same thing than pointer dereferencing. By using the right notation, the code gets less confusing (imo).

`*(p + i)` is a synonym of `p[i]`  therefore `*pp` is same as `*(pp + 0)` which is the same as `pp[0]`